Identification of unknown module with chip labeled "300-800 2005-5-5"
I found a component on the street that looks like a camera or an infrared sensor. After disassembling it, I noticed it has a central chip with the inscription "300-800 2005-5-5."
I’ve tried searching for information on this chip but haven’t had any luck. Could anyone help me identify this module or suggest tools for further investigation?
Thanks in advance!




I'm not sure what the difference between the second and third pictures are but 2005-5-5 is very likely a date code. I'm trying to figure out what you mean by "central chip". Are you talking about potentially an image sensor or its processor (ISP)? The IR LEDs are probably the four devices you see in the four corners of the PCB, i.e. R7, R12, R10, R5(?)

none there I corrected it, thanks for the warning

This looks like a USB webcam built (cheaply) around an SOC that has the image sensor and processor in one package.
The protruding ball on a stem suggests it has been dislocated from a swivel mount. The LDR RG (it looks like to me) and 4x infrared LEDs could allow it work in various lighting conditions.
It should be obvious from the capacitors which is +5 and which is GND, which leaves just the two data lines.
Of course it might be something else, but that's what it looks like to me. And, of course, there are risks plugging anything in to a USB port attached to something you care about.

P.S. now that you've added the back photo, the Shenzhen-based manufacturer Liangtian Technology appears to be at http://www.eloam.cn (and they make many camera-related products).
